# Perl: change element/s in array of hashes

Tags: arrays, perl

How do I change an element/s in an array of hashes in Perl?

Suppose I have the following array and want to change the price of an item:

```
my @clothes = (
    { item => 'Jeans',  colour => 'Blue',  price => 50 },
    { item => 'Shawl',  colour => 'Red',   price => 30 },
    { item => 'Blazer', colour => 'Brown', price => 100 },
    { item => 'Suit',   colour => 'Black', price => 40 },
    { item => 'Top',    colour => 'White', price => 25 }
);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't have a two-dimensional array---you have an array of hashrefs. If you wanted to change the price of a specific item, you would need to know the array index that holds the hash reference it belongs to.

```
$clothes[1]->{price} = 42;
```

For additional things you can do with your array of hashes, see the aptly named [Arrays of Hashes](http://perldoc.perl.org/perldsc.html#ARRAYS-OF-HASHES) section of [perldsc](http://perldoc.perl.org/perldsc.html).

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for

Answer (score 6):

What you have there is called an array of hashes. More precisely, what you have there is an array of references to hashes. That means

```
$clothes[3]
```

is a reference to a hash, so

```
$clothes[3]->{price}
```

is the value of the `price` element of that hash. The `->` can be omitted between indexes, so the following is equivalent:

```
$clothes[3]{price}
```

That means you want

```
$clothes[3]{price} = 45;
```

---

If you don't know the index of the element you want, you can scan the array. Remember that each element of the array is a reference to one of the hashes.

```
for my $clothes_item (@clothes) {
    if ($clothes_item->{item} eq 'Suit') {
       $clothes_item->{price} = 45;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use Data::Dumper;

my @clothes = 
    (
        {item => 'Jeans', colour => 'Blue', price => 50},
        {item => 'Shawl', colour => 'Red', price => 30},
        {item => 'Blazer', colour => 'Brown', price => 100},
        {item => 'Suit', colour => 'Black', price => 40},
        {item => 'Top', colour => 'White', price => 25}    
    );

for my $next_item ( @clothes ){
        $next_item->{price} = 0.99
}

print Dumper( \@clothes );
```

Comment: @MattJacob All items 99 cents, everything must go!

Comment: @ThisSuitIsBlackNot Hahaha